# Oscillatory solution of a differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the oscillatory solution $y=cosωt$ where y is real and show that this   corresponds to the real part of $\frac{dx}{dt}= iωx, x(0) = 1$. where $x = e^{iωt}$.

This is what I've done:

let $y=Re(x_0 e^{iwt})$ and let $x_o=a+ib$ then by subbing in $e^{iwt}=coswt+isinwt$ you get $y=Re(acoswt-bsinwt)$ and by using the initial condition of $x=1$ when $t=0$ you get that $a=1$ and so $y=coswt$.

Is this what the question is looking for?

I'm not sure how to or if i need to show that $b=0$, or if my method shows the $Re(\frac{dx}{dt})=coswt=y$.

Comment: Maybe you mean $y=\Re (x)=\Re(e^{i\omega t})$...but i can go wrong. However in this way it should be trivial

Comment: My interpretation of the question would be to show that $\Re(\frac{dx}{dt})=y=coswt$ but i'm not sure that it works, but $y$ is trivially the $\Re(x)$.

Comment: But if $x=e^{i\omega t}$ it follows that $\Re(\frac{dx}{dt})=\Re(i\omega e^{i\omega t})=\Re[i\omega(cos\omega t+i sen\omega t)]=\Re(-\omega sen\omega t+i\omega cos\omega t)=-\omega sen\omega t$...

Comment: yeah which isn't correct so thats why i'm not sure what the question asks

Comment: Try reading again the question..maybe you overlooked something